# How to Iterate the JSON object and add a key value pair object dynamically using its hierarchy level in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, key-value

I want this JSON to be iterated and add a key value pair with its level.

**For example:**

The first level hierarchy should be level 0 and second level should be level 1, and so on.

```
var json = [{
  "name": "parent 1",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "child 1",
      "children": [
            {
            "name": "child 11"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
      "name": "child 2"
    }
  ]
}];
```

**Expected json:**

```
var json = [
{
  "name": "parent 1",
  "level": "0",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "child 1",
      "level": "1",
      "children": [
            {
            "name": "child 11",
            "level": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
      "name": "child 2",
      "level": "1"
    }
  ]
}];
```

Comment: Please don't repost [poorly-received questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59809386/157247) without fixing the issues identified the last time you posted them.

Comment: As I said before: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Also as I said before: That isn't a "json array." JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: And: [*For-each over an array in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) seems at least relevant, but didn't want to dupehammer.

Comment: I don't know why it is marked as poorly received question. When i post the question, the similarly answered questions are not related to this.

Comment: Read the above, and you'll know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by using [`Array.protoype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can achieve the required goal.

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Please find a possible solution for your question:

```js
const data = [{"name": "parent 1","children": [{"name": "child 1","children": [{"name": "child 11"}]},{"name": "child 2"}]}];

const addLevel = (array, level) => {
  if (!level) { level = 0; }
        
  return array.map(e => {
    if (e.children) { e.children = addLevel(e.children, level + 1); }
    return { ...e, level };
  });
};

const result = addLevel(data);
console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the solution man! Can you tell me what does the below code does? I believe you are using spread operator.
`return {...e,level}`

Comment: @sureshmg Yes, that's called spread syntax. Technically I'm copying the current element from each iteration and adding `level` to the returned value. Read further here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lodash to loop over your Objects and Array:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach

Answer (score 0):

for

```
var json = [{
  "name": "parent 1",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "child 1",
      "children": [
            {
            "name": "child 11"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
      "name": "child 2"
    }
  ]
}];
```

A Simple Solution is

```
function mapping(ar , i = 0 ) {
    ar.map(el => {        
        el.level = i ;
        if(el.children){
            mapping(el.children , i+1);
        }
    });
}
mapping(json)



let solution = JSON.stringify(json) ;
console.log(solution)

[
{"name":"parent 1",
 "children":[{
              "name":"child 1",
              "children":[{
                           "name":"child 11",
                           "level":2,
                         }],
               "level":1
                },
               {
                "name":"child 2",
                "level":1
                }], 
 "level":0}
]
```